# bind ctrl-h to move left in vim under insert mode with vundle

Tags: vim-plugin, vim

i am from china, so may my english is poor.

i used to write

```
:map! <C-h> <Left> 
:map! <C-l> <Right>
```

in my .vimrc file to bind the ctrl-h to move left under insert mode and ctrl-l to move right. and they work well.

but after i use the vundle plugin to manage my plugin. the ctrl-h does not work now.It prefer to del and move left under insert mode, that is not my wish. but ctrl-l always work fine.

is there something wrong with ctrl-h , I think vundle affect it, or bind ctrl-h before me.

Comment: I met the same problem in gvim, add tag gvim.

Comment: @zdd I am not very understand "add tag gvim", can explain more? thx

Comment: I mean retag it to add tag gvim, tag is a label which your questions belongs to, you add vim and vim-plugin when you post this question, and I want to add gvim, clear?

Comment: @zdd oh, sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. get it. I add it alreadly. And I have my problem some progress.  you can input :imap to see which one occupy the map <C-h>

Comment: I use imap already, but it still not work, and :verbose map <C-h> said there is no mapping for <C-h>.

Comment: @zdd so that says your map is not success, I think.  My problem here is there are two maps, one by me ,another by a plugin. I remove the plugin, then i go ok now.

Comment: last I solve this by using another repo from https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose, It doesn't have conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check what who define it before your.

```
:verbose map <C-h>
:verbose map <C-l>
```

Comment: thx, that works. but i use :verbose map! <C-h> because i map it under insert mode.  it cause by a plugin called "AutoClose", at the ~/.vim/bundle/AutoClose/plugin/autoclose.vim , I don't know how to edit it to make it works fine, and i fear if i edit cause the plugin not work or can't update from vundle, or vundle update it to make it to origion. So I del remove the plugin through vundle , then come fine now. So, I lost the "AutoClose" plugin.

Comment: @mygoare If you want to map it just on insert mode, you shouldn't use `map`. `map` effect to insert/normal/command mode. use `imap` instead.

Comment: thx, you are right, but if i use map! , i can use my map with insert mode and command line mode.

Answer (score 1):

i have this mapping for the same goal. it works both in gvim, terminal (rxvt) and tty.

```
" move cursor in Insert Mode 
inoremap <C-h> <C-o>h
inoremap <C-j> <C-o>j
inoremap <C-k> <C-o>k
inoremap <C-l> <C-o>l
```